# Error in Makefile calling sed with comment character

Tags: sed, lua, makefile

I'm trying to build [`lstrip`](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lstrip), a Lua utility for compressing Lua source code. I'm trying to build for Lua 5.1.3 on OS X v10.10.3.

I have downloaded and extracted the Lua 5.1.3 source code and modified the Makefile for `lstrip` to point to this directory. However, when I run `make`, I get this output:

```
cc -I/usr/local/src/lua-5.1.3/src -I/usr/local/src/lua-5.1.3/src -O2 -Wall -Wextra -O2    -c -o lstrip.o lstrip.c
lstrip.c:33:14: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
             ^
1 warning generated.
sed '/void luaX_next/i#include "proxy.c"' /usr/local/src/lua-5.1.3/src/llex.c > llex.c
sed: 1: "/void luaX_next/i#inclu ...": command i expects \ followed by text
make: *** [llex.c] Error 1
```

This is what the relevant Makefile command looks like:

```
llex.c:
    sed '/void luaX_next/i#include "proxy.c"' $(LUASRC)/$@ > $@
```

I *think* that this is because the `#` in the sed command is being treated like an actual comment, but I'm not sure.

How can I fix the Makefile, or manually run the steps, to get `lstrip` built?

---

Full copy of the Makefile follows, in case it matters:

```
# makefile for lstrip

# change these to reflect your Lua installation (Lua 5.1!)
LUA= /usr/local/src/lua-5.1.3
LUAINC= $(LUA)/src
LUALIB= $(LUA)/src
LUASRC= $(LUA)/src

# no need to change anything below here
CFLAGS= $(INCS) $(WARN) -O2 $G
WARN= -O2 -Wall -Wextra

INCS= -I$(LUAINC) -I$(LUASRC)
LIBS= -L$(LUALIB) -llua -lm

MYNAME= lstrip
MYLIB= $(MYNAME)
T= $(MYNAME)
OBJS= $(MYNAME).o llex.o
TEST= test.lua

all:    test

test:   $T
    $T $(TEST)

$T: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

llex.c:
    sed '/void luaX_next/i#include "proxy.c"' $(LUASRC)/$@ > $@

llex.o: proxy.c

clean:
    -rm -f $(OBJS) core core.* a.out $(MYNAME)

# eof
```

---

Hand-build solution:

1. `cp /usr/local/src/lua-5.1.3/src/llex.c .`
2. Hand-edit llex.c to add the line `#include "proxy.c"` before the line starting with `void luaX_next` (line 446 for me).
3. Now run `make`, which will succeed.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. It does work in Linux, but not in Mac OS X. I'll try to fix it soon. Thanks for the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line works in Mac OS X and in Linux:

```
sed '/void luaX_next/{h;s/.*/#include "proxy.c"/;p;g;}' $(LUASRC)/$@ > $@
```

Comment: I wonder whether this can be shortened: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31151156/107090.

Comment: What you have there now works (as I suspect you know). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer in the sed manual, and it is in the Makefile lines

```
llex.c:
    sed '/void luaX_next/i#include "proxy.c"' $(LUASRC)/$@ > $@
```

Some variable expansion takes place here:
$(LUASRC) is expanded to the variable set above -> $(LUA)/src. Recurse as needed.
$@ is replaced with the current target (llex.c)

So this recipe says:
In order to obtain the target llex.c (which will be processed later through other recipes), apply a stream editing command to the file $LUASRC/llex.c and write it to llex.c.

The stream editing command is: look for text "void luaX_next", before printing it, insert line "#include "proxy.c"".
Problem is, the command to do this is not "i" but "i\(newline)", which conflicts with a requirement of Makefiles that recipes must be on a single line.

I suspect that in order to fix your Makefile you need to use a different command than sed; awk can fit the bill although it's a bit more complex.

Comment: Interesting. I can't +1 this without verification; further, I'd be surprised if this is the problem, since I'm certain that I was able to successfully build `lstrip` in the past, and further I do not think that (seasoned programming veteran) lhf made a mistake that would prevent this from compiling. This program has been around for almost 9 years. What you are describing sounds like it would never have worked; I doubt that's true. I suspect it's a problem related to recent OS X utility changes.

Comment: Ah! However, your English-language decoding of the sed command allowed me to perform it myself by hand, and at that point the program compiled. That alone is worth a +1, and perhaps the acceptance. :)

Comment: @Phrogz: There is a GNU extension that allows you to omit the first backslash-newline combo. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Text_002c-appending-129) (it is documented under the `a` command).