# sed oneliner to add a line before another line

Tags: sed, makefile

I need to add a line with `bar` before each line with `foo` with `sed`.

I need to do this in a Makefile and so I cannot use `i\` because it needs a newline in standard `sed` (not GNU sed, e.g., the one in Mac OS X) and this cannot be done in a Makefile (at least, not nicely).

The solution I found is:

```
sed '/foo/{h;s/.*/bar/;p;g;}' < in > out
```

This saves the line, replaces its contents with `bar`, prints the new line, restores the old line (and prints it by default).

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Motivated by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148767/error-in-makefile-calling-sed-with-comment-character.

Answer (score 3):

#### BSD sed

This will put `bar` before every line with `foo`:

```
sed $'/foo/{s/^/bar\\\n/;}' in >out
```

#### GNU sed

This will put `bar` before every line with `foo`:

```
sed '/foo/{s/^/bar\n/;}' in >out
```

#### How it works

- `/foo/`

  This selects lines that contain `foo`.
- `s/^/bar\n/`

  `^` matches the beginning of the line.  Thus, for the selected lines, this substitutes in `bar\n` at the beginning of the line.  This effectively adds a new line to precede the one containing `foo`.

  Under GNU, one can write `\n` and sed interprets it as a newline.  This doesn't work under BSD sed.  Hence the different version.

Comment: @lhf Wow, that is limiting.  I did [some reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421478/how-do-i-use-a-new-line-replacement-in-a-bsd-sed) and updated the answer with something that reportedly should work.

Comment: You don't actually need the braces, `$'/foo/s/^/bar\\\n/'` works. Though it can be easier to lose track of which part you're looking at.

Comment: the gnu one can be trimmed a little bit: `s/^.*foo/bar\n&/`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I presume that, for BSD, your version would become `$'s/^.*foo/bar\\\n&/'`.  I would add it to the answer if I could test it on OSX to be sure.

Comment: @John1024 sorry, i have no idea about BSD.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/foo/ibar' file
```

I'm not sure why you say you need a newline but just incase the inserted line needs to longer than one line you can employ bash so:

```
sed $'/foo/ibar\\\nbaz' file
```